# How to get all information concerning a Windows service?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, windows-services

On one computer, a Windows service is created.

I have tried to create the same one on another computer, but this seems not to work.

In order to solve my issue, I'm planning to ask for all Windows service related information, and compare those on both computers.

Although this seems logical, it's not that straightforward: there are the commands `sc query`, `sc qc`, `sc qdescription`, ..., which gives me the anxiety that there might be some configuration I might be missing.

Is there a single commandline command, which can show all Windows service related information?

Just to give you an idea of the current situation:

### sc qc

```
Prompt>sc qc Application_Server
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: Application_Server
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : E:\Application\Server 2\ApplicationServer.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Application_Server
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

### sc query

```
Prompt>sc query Application_Server

SERVICE_NAME: Application_Server
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

### sc qdescription

```
Prompt>sc qdescription Application_Server
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: Application_Server
DESCRIPTION:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of a Windows service's information is stored in the registry using the short service name. For example, using `spooler`:

```
c:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\spooler

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\spooler
    DependOnService    REG_MULTI_SZ  RPCSS\0http
    Description        REG_SZ        @%systemroot%\system32\spoolsv.exe,-2
    DisplayName        REG_SZ        @%systemroot%\system32\spoolsv.exe,-1
    ImagePath          REG_EXPAND_SZ %SystemRoot%\System32\spoolsv.exe
    ObjectName         REG_SZ        LocalSystem
    [etc...]
```

You can export just this registry key and import it into another computer to migrate the entire service. You'll still need to install the underlying program identically, `ApplicationServer.exe` in your example. You **do** need to set the credentials again if the service is set to "Log on as" a user account, as those are not exportable.

---

To get more readable details about specific service properties, check out the other service control `q` commands:

```
c:\>sc.exe ?

qc--------------Queries the configuration information for a service.
qdescription----Queries the description for a service.
qfailure--------Queries the actions taken by a service upon failure.
qfailureflag----Queries the failure actions flag of a service.
qsidtype--------Queries the service SID type of a service.
qprivs----------Queries the required privileges of a service.
qtriggerinfo----Queries the trigger parameters of a service.
qpreferrednode--Queries the preferred NUMA node of a service.
qmanagedaccount-Queries whether a services uses an account with a password managed by LSA.
qprotection-----Queries the process protection level of a service.
quserservice----Queries for a local instance of a user service template.
```

Comment: Can you confirm that all information, to be retrieved by `sc qc`, `sc query`, `sc qdescription`, ..., is all just a subset of `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\<Service_Name>`?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, all the service info is in that key. Be aware that `sc query` returns info about the *current* state of services, which is not stored in the registry (running or stopped, etc.)